# Изменение цвета текста всплывающей подсказки QToolTip

Tags: python, gui, pyqt, qss, qtooltip

Как изменить цвет текста всплывающей подсказки QToolTip или её фон?

**main.py**:

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.initUi()
        
    def initUi(self):  
        self.setStyleSheet('background : #7c7c7c')
        self.mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.b = QPushButton('Text')
        self.b.setStyleSheet('background : #000221; color: #ececec')
        self.b.setToolTip('Tooltip')
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.b)
        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)

        
app = QApplication([])
e = Example()
e.show()
app.exec()
```

---

Однако работает оно не так, как мне бы хотелось:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пробуйте:

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUi()

    def initUi(self):  
#        self.setStyleSheet('background : #7c7c7c')

        self.setStyleSheet('''
        QWidget {
            background : yellow;
        }
        QPushButton {
            background : #aa0221; 
            color: #ececec;}

        QToolTip { 
            color: #ffffff; 
            background-color: #2a82da; 
            border: 1px solid white; }
        ''')
        self.mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.b = QPushButton('Text')

#        self.b.setStyleSheet('background : #aa0221; color: #ececec')

        self.b.setToolTip('Tooltip')

        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.b)

        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)

app = QApplication([])
e = Example()
e.show()
app.exec()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]